# How to isolate my own OpenGL calls inside a third-party process?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am writing small tool that is drawing OpenGL overlay on top of the game which is closed source. The game is using SDL, so I am just hooking into `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` and doing my own stuff. However, this kind of hooking results in some side effects in the game itself. I found a solution that is basically wrapping around my own calls with deprecated `glPushAttrib/glPopAttrib`. But this solves only half of the problems. I am still getting random texture flickering in the game (I meant game textures, mine are showing fine). What could be the reason of this flickering? Can my own textures interfere with game textures? Do I need to isolate my own calls and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the reason of this flickering?

If the game uses shaders, then glPushAttrib / glPopAttrib will not take care of all the state you may be clobbering with. The attribute stack has been deprecated and the program may use states that are either *not* covered by it, or where certain attribute bits in compatibility profile have been reused or expanded to cover further state. I recommend not using the attribute stack at all, because it's hard to get right.

> Can my own textures interfere with game textures?

Yes. Say you left a 2D texture active in a texture unit that's later being used for a 1D texture. If the host program *does not* use shaders, then the GL_TEXTURE_2D will take precedence over the GL_TEXTURE_1D. It's a (IMHO poor) design choice of OpenGL that you can have multiple texture targets being bound to the same texture unit at the same time and which one is used to deliver texels depends on the individual targets' precedence.

> Do I need to isolate my own calls

Yes.

> and how can I do it?

Two possible solutions:

1. Create separate OpenGL context for just your own stuff. Use `{wgl,glX}GetCurrentContext` and `{wglGetCurrentDC,glXGetCurrentDrawable}` to retrieve the OpenGL context and drawable active at the moment you're "jumping" in. If you don't have a context already, you can use the drawable just retrieved to create a matching OpenGL context. Optionally install a namespace sharing. Switch to your context, draw your stuff and switch back to the host program one's. – Major drawback: Switching OpenGL contexts is quite expensive.
2. Before switching state around, use `glGet…` to retrieve the state active before doing so and restore the old state before returning to the host program.

Comment: I'm already using second approach. I have stack-allocated helper class for `glEnable` that restores everything back in destructor, but it seems like either it doesn't help, or there is something else that I'm changing during my calls. The game does use shaders, thus the problem is not related to textures.

Comment: First approach seems like what I actually need. But affecting game performance is undesirable. I (probably) have to switch contexts every single frame. I never used this functions before and I don't know what "context" actually is, but I'll try it.

Comment: @Xpast: **Everything** in OpenGL hinges on render contexts. An understanding of what an OpenGL context is and how they behave it vitally important for any kind of advanced OpenGL programming. In short terms a OpenGL context is kind of like a "class instance" in which all the textures, shaders, framebuffer objects and state is collected. This allows the operating system to segregate OpenGL operation between processes, but also allows a process to isolate things. Also contexts can be kind of "connected" so they share their data, but state is separated.

Comment: @Xpast: There's more OpenGL state than just what goes through `glEnable` practically every OpenGL call that *does not* draw stuff is a state changing operating. If you look at the reference documentation for every OpenGL function, most of them have a section "Associated Gets", which specify which state is altered and how to query it.